# Using "this" inside named function on a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write a simple jQuery plugin and I need some code to run on both load and window resize so I wrote a function inside the plugin.

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.responsiveNav = function() {

        function enable_responsive_nav() {

            if( this.hasClass('class') ) { 
              //do stuff
            }

        }

        $(window).resize(function(e) {
            enable_responsive_nav();
        });
        enable_responsive_nav();

        return this;

    };

}( jQuery ));

$('nav').responsiveNav();
```

The problem is 'this' doesn't seem to be recognized inside the function. I tried passing it as a function argument:

```
enable_responsive_nav( this )
```

...but then I get an error on the console saying hasClass() 'is not a function'.

I guess I could do it without the function out and then bind the window resize event outside the plugin, but I'm trying to keep that to a single call and I'm sure that what I'm missing is very simple.

Comment: Does enable_responsive_nav.bind(this)() work?

Comment: When you added `enable_responsive_nav( this )` Did you also add something like this: `function enable_responsive_nav(el)` and then call `if( el.hasClass('class') ) { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common solution is to create a local variable called `that` or `self` in the scope where `this` has the expected value, and then to refer to the local variable in the scope of the inner function:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.responsiveNav = function() {
        var self = this; // local variable
        function enable_responsive_nav() {

            if( self.hasClass('class') ) { // self is in scope
              //do stuff
            }

        }

        $(window).resize(function(e) {
            enable_responsive_nav();
        });
        enable_responsive_nav();

        return this;

    };

}( jQuery ));

$('nav').responsiveNav();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried passing it as a function argument:
>
> ```
> enable_responsive_nav( this )
> ```

Let's follow the chain through:

jQuery will call your event callback with `this` referencing the **DOM element** (not jQuery object) that the event was hooked on. So you can do this:

```
enable_responsive_nav( $(this) );
```

...with

```
if( arg.hasClass('class') ) { 
    //do stuff
}
```

Or

```
enable_responsive_nav.call(this);
```

with

```
if($(this).hasClass('class') ) { 
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @BioXD: If `arg` is a jQuery object, you'd do `arg.find(".selector")`. Fundamentally, just be aware of what kind of object your variables or `this` refer to and use the properties and methods that kind of object has.